# vbs script to display the files and folder on the desktop but this is not running and throwing an error

Tags: vbscript

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DesktopPath=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
'Files count
msgbox "the no of files on the desktop is:"
&fso.GetFolder(DesktopPath).Files.count
'Folders count
msgbox "the no of folder on the desktop is:"
&fso.GetFolder(DesktopPath).SubFolders.count
```

[image: the above mentioned code is displaying the following error]

Comment: The lines starting with `&fso` should be part of the previous lines, not standing on their own. (If you want to break a line, end the incomplete lines with `_`)

Comment: @CherryDT Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You should add `_` at the end of the comment of your `MsgBox` for break a line  :

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DesktopPath=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
'Files count
msgbox "The N° of files on the desktop is : "_
& fso.GetFolder(DesktopPath).Files.count
'Folders count
msgbox "The N° of folder on the desktop is : "_
& fso.GetFolder(DesktopPath).SubFolders.count
```

Comment: Thank you that worked very well

Comment: It's been covered many times as you will be well aware @hackoo.

Comment: @vadiraj Please take Stack Overflow (SO) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to say thanks on SO by accepting an answer on being helpful by clicking on gray check mark symbol left to an answer.
See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)
A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.

Comment: @Hackoo Please read the Stack Overflow (SO) [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn when to and not to answer a question (especially "Answer well-asked questions" section).